# How to determine (at runtime) if TensorFlow Lite is using a GPU or not?

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

Is there a way for me to **ensure** or at least **determine at runtime** the correct accelerator (CPU, GPU) is used when using the TensorFlow Lite library?

Although I had followed the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu#trying_the_gpu_delegate_on_your_own_model), and set the `Interpreter.Options()` object to use a GPU delegate on a device with a GPU (Samsung S9), its highly likely to be using the CPU in some cases. For example, if you use a quantized model with a default delegate options object, it will default to using the CPU, because `quantizedModelsAllowed` is set to false. I am almost sure that even though the options object passed to the interpreter had a `GPUDelegate`, that the CPU was used instead. Unfortunately, I had to guess based on speed of inference and accuracy.

There was no warning, I just noticed slower inference time and improved accuracy (because in my case the GPU was acting weirdly, giving me wrong values, and I am trying to figure out why as a separate concern). Currently, I have to guess if the GPU/ CPU is being used, and react accordingly. Now, I think there are other cases like this where it falls back to the CPU, but I don't want to guess.

---

I have heard of AGI (Android GPU Inspector), it currently only supports 3 pixel devices. It would have been nice to use this to see the GPU get used in the profiler. I have also tried Samsungs GPUWatch, this simply does not work (on both OpenGL and Vulkan), as my app doesn't use either of these APIs (it doesn't render stuff, it uses tensorflow!).

Comment: Are you sure your model is compatible with GPU delegate? also fyi GPU delegate is currently support int8 quantized models. Just try to use the benchmark tool to determine what is used and what configuration is optimal for your phone

Comment: Hey @Farmaker, yes I am sure, because I have been able to 'prove' that the GPU is used in some cases. (For example, when using a GPU Delegate, I get reduced accuracy because the GPU delegate defaults to downcasting to float16 automatically, which reduces accuracy.). I will try the C++ benchmark tool soon, but have tried the Android one in the past.

Comment: I have done numerous android projects with TensorFlow Lite models. Check my repo https://github.com/farmaker47 . I have used CPU, GPU, NNAPI and Hexagon delegate. You can see more details and usage here https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/delegates . If you want send me your tflite model at farmaker47@gmail.com to pass it through the benchmark tool with an experimental colab notebook and give you the results.

Comment: Hey @Farmaker, I have tried the C++ and Android benchmarking tools, I like them as I can now run tests on devices more quickly. It is a bit annoying to use `adb logcat` though. However, I feel like they're not giving me what I want (to be sure that the correct delegate is used) in my app?

Comment: Dear @Farmaker, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c902rdwe9stzskg/VggFace2SeNet.tflite?dl=0) is my tflite model (which is created using the [keras-vggface library](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-vggface) and the tflite python converter), and then I added the Model metadata to link back to the original author.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look and come with the results.

Answer (score 2):

I will place my results here after using the benchmark tool:

Firstly you can see the model with CPU usage without XNNPack:
[image]

Secondly model with CPU with XNNPack:
[image]

Thirdly model with GPU usage!!!!!:
[image]

And lastly with Hexagon or NNAPI delegate:
[image]

As you can see model is been processed by GPU. Also I used 2 randomly selected phones. If you want any particular device please say it to me. Finally you can download all results from benchmark tool [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eF3Yni_fCMZaG74KVvARIhftGjHhLARD/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks Farmaker. However, I've actually tried all the delegates in my testing too. Although the GPU is fast, its really inaccurate because its quantizing the model automatically (downcasting to 16bit). Additionally, my question is about determining which delegate is being used at Runtime in my app. I feel like both answerers don't understand what my title says 

Comment: I like your detail and efforts though, so I have upvoted.

Comment: I will ask a TensorFlow Advocate that is a friend of mine about how to determine the use of delegates during runtime. When I have an answer I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by TensorFlow advocate:

Q= `What is happening when we set to use a specific delegate but the phone cannot support it? Let's say I set to use a Hexagon delegate and the phone cannot use it. It is going to fall back to CPU usage?`

A= It should fallback to the CPU.

Q= `What about if I set GPU and this delegate cannot support the specific model. Does it fall back to the CPU or it crashes?`

A= It should also fallback to CPU but the tricky thing is sometimes a delegate "thinks" it could support an op at initialization time, but during runtime "realize" that it can't support the particular configuration of the op in the particular model. In such cases, the delegate crashes.

Q= `Is there a way to determine what delegate is used during runtime despite what we have set to use?`
A= You can look at the logcat, or use the benchmark tool to run the model on the particular phone to find out.

Answer (score 0):

As Farmaker mentioned, TFLite's benchmarking & accuracy tooling is the best way for you to judge how a delegate will behave for your use-case (your model & device).

First, use the [benchmark tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/delegates#latency_memory_footprint) to check latencies with various configurations (for delegates, use params like `use_gpu=true`). See [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement) for a detailed explanation of the tool, and pre-built binaries for you to use via adb. You can also use the param `--enable_op_profiling=true` to see which ops from the graph get accelerated by the delegate.

Then, if you want to check accuracy/correctness of a delegate for your model (i.e. whether the delegate behaves like CPU would numerically), look at [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/delegates#accuracy_correctness) for tooling details.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this doesn't answer my question at all, and is just repeating what is in the documentation.

Comment: I misunderstood the question then. Do you want to check if an accelerator is working *at runtime*? Or during development? If its the former, I am curious about the use-case. If the latter, is there a reason the benchmark_model tool isn't satisfactory to let you know how your model latency is affected? If it shows that a model is accelerated, then thats how it will be at runtime unless the backend (for eg OpenCL) mysteriously misbehaves.

Comment: Hi Sachin, yes I mean at runtime. The reason is, as a developer, its important to know what is happening in the app for various reasons (debugging, performance improvements, experiments). In some cases, even though I specified a GPUDelegate through the `Interpreter.Options`, it will fall back to CPU (i.e. when GPU quantization is disabled/ the default). Thus, unless someone knows this behaviour or can predict the GPU is not being used, they will think the GPU is working fine.

Comment: To make matters worse, we currently don't have a good way of measuring GPU usage on device (AGI is in beta, and only supports latest Pixel devices). It would be great if I can see the GPU being used, and even better by how much. This way I can optimize the app for a specific device (i.e. increase batch size, although you'd need a separate model for this because the GPU delegate doesn't support dynamic tensors). I'm not doing your off-the-mill classification task 

Comment: You'd probably be able to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64959850/serialize-and-deserialize-protobufs-through-cli) as well, as it involves the `inference_diff` tools protobuf. Im not sure why tool outputs in protobuf? I guess its easier to save to protobuf in the C++ application. And for CLI users, they can just easily redirect stdout with `> inference_diff.txt`.